# C- int first declaration in For loop gcc

Tags: c, gcc

Why this `C` code  can not be compiled with `gcc` ?

```
for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
 //some code here
}
```

I know there is a solution which consist on delaring `j`out of the `For` loop. But, is there any option in `gcc` to do that in `C` program ?

Comment: What do you mean by "can not be executed"? Surely if it compiled, you *can* then execute it...!!??

Comment: Adding an error message would have made this question clear.

Comment: Use -std=c99 or -std=gnu99

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C99 and latter allows this feature. Compile your code in C99 mode `-std=C99`.

### C11: 6.8.5.3 The for statement:

> 1 The statement
>
> ```
> for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
> ```
>
> behaves as follows: The expression *expression-2* is the controlling expression that is
>   evaluated before each execution of the loop body. The expression *expression-3* is
>   evaluated as a void expression after each execution of the loop body. **If *clause-1* is a
>   declaration**<sup>1</sup>, the scope of any identifiers it declares is the remainder of the declaration and the entire loop, including the other two expressions; it is reached in the order of execution before the first evaluation of the controlling expression. If *clause-1* is an expression, it is evaluated as a void expression before the first evaluation of the controlling expression.158)

---

<sub>1.Emphasis is mine.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

The error message says it all (at least on `gcc-4.6.3`):

```
error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
```

If you add `-std=c99` at the compilation command:

```
gcc -std=c99 test.c
```

then it should compile